# VSCode Extension - Grammar Injection Into Multiple Languages

Tags: visual-studio-code, grammar, code-injection, textmate

I'd like my extension to apply to both HTMl and Markdown.

I understand I can use

```
"injectTo": [
    "text.html.derivative"
    "text.html.markdown"
],
```

But that doesn't work on it's own because I need to somehow have both in

```
"injectionSelector": "L:text.html.derivative",
```

How do I add Markdown to my `injectionSelection` in addition to HTML?

Comment: so your language's grammer is... the union of multiple other languages' grammers?

Comment: @starball no it's a templating engine which supports both Markdown and HTML so the grammar needs to apply in both

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by treating it as a language rather than a grammar injection and simply including `text.html.derivative` and `text.html.markdown` in the `tmLanguage.json` file.